# После запонения формы в context_processors ошибка ValueError at / dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required Django

Tags: python, django, шаблонизаторы

Мне надо сделать заказ звонка, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправки номера телефона, происходил редирект.

Сейчас, введеный номер отправляется, однако после нажатия на кнопку отправки, сейчас мне выдается ошибка: ***dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required***

Непойму как сделать, потому что для контекст процессора должен передаваться словарь..
 У меня было в конекст процессоре для редиректа `return render(request, 'mail/mail_f.html', {'form': form})` но тогда ни одна страница не открывалась, выдавало ошибку *****RecursionError at /
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object***

Для отображения на всех страницах, форма сделана в *context_processors.py*:

```
def call_order(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CallOrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            'Заказ звонка с сайта',
            form.cleaned_data['content'],
            '@mail.ru',
            ['@mail.ru'],
        )
        html_content = f'Презвоните мне: { form.cleaned_data["content"] }'
        mail.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        mail.send()

        if call_order:
            messages.success(request, 'Письмо отправлено')
            return redirect('../sendhead/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка отправки')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Ошибка валидации')
else:
    form = CallOrderForm()
return {'form': form}
```

часть html из хэдэра для отправки:

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.content }}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Перезвоните</button>
      </form>
```

settings.py

```
'context_processors': [
            'mail.context_processors.call_order',
```

Python 3.7.9, Django 3.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кому интересно, то исправил вот так:

> 1. Подправил reutrn в def call_order и перенес ее во view

```
def call_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CallOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                'Заказ звонка с сайта',
                form.cleaned_data['content'],
                '@mail.ru',
                ['@mail.ru'],
            )
            html_content = f'Презвоните мне: { form.cleaned_data["content"] }'
            mail.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            mail.send()

            if call_order:
                messages.success(request, 'Письмо отправлено')
                return redirect('../sendhead/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Ошибка отправки')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка валидации')
    else:
        form = CallOrderForm()
    return render(request, 'mail/mail_f.html', {'form': form})
```

> 2. Поправил context_processors.py:

```
def call_orders(request):
    form = CallOrderForm()
    return {'form': form}
```

> 3.В html шаблоне указал action - страницу обработки формы

```
<form method="post" action="/mail/sendhead/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.content }}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Перезвоните</button>
  </form>
```

Готово, теперь заказ звонка находится в хедере на всех страницах.